# SyntaxError "break outside loop"

Tags: python

```
supplied_username = input("Please enter your name. ")
print("Your username has been created and is", supplied_username)
supplied_password = input("Now please create a password. ")
file = open("Login.txt","a")
file.write (supplied_username)
file.write (",")
file.write (supplied_password)
file.write("\n")
file.close()

logged_in = False
with open('Login.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        supplied_username, supplied_password = line.split(',')
username = input("please enter your username")
if username == supplied_username:
    password = input("please enter your password")
if password == supplied_password:
    logged_in = True
    break

if logged_in:
    print("welcome!")
else:
    ("please, register an account")
```

i get a syntax error of "breaking outside loop"
why?
im creating a login program which asks the username to register by entering a username and password which gets saved in a text file, then logging in by entering the username and password they just entered to register. if it matches the one saved in the text file, they have successfully logged in, if it doesnt they have to re enter it.

edit: i've fixed it by moving the 'break' 4 spaces forward. but i now get a syntax error of 'unexpected indent'
help please.

Comment: Indentation is important in python and your break is indeed outside of your for-loop - at least if your code looks exactly like the code you've posted here. The error message should point you to the exact line.

Comment: you need 8 spaces not 4 - and not only `break` but whole block.

Comment: Break can only be used under a loop.. So if you try to use it under a solo if statement (which is not under any loop) It will always give you an error

Comment: thankyou. ive fixed it but now i get a syntax error of 'unexpected indent'.. please help! and yes, my code looks exactly like this and i use python 3.4.GUI.

Comment: I think you should indent your both `if` statements under that for loop

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
with open('Login.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            supplied_username, supplied_password = line.split(',')
            supplied_username=supplied_username.strip()
            supplied_password=supplied_password.strip('\n')
            username = input("please enter your username")
            if username == supplied_username:
                password = input("please enter your password")
            if password == supplied_password:
                logged_in = True
                break

if logged_in:
    print("welcome!")
else:
    print("please, register an account")
```

After resolving problem of `Indentation`, the next problem of space.What you store in your file it return it with append `space` on it.
So first `strip` and then check.